# raid 1 - single disk

Tags: linux, raid-1

I'm reaching out to you as I messed up my raid 1. 
It all started with a broken disk. I replaced the disk with a new one. The sync seems to be successfull. However, I'm getting tons of errors and the raid is not available anymore. At least I would like to rescue my data before I take any further steps.

```
xxx@ubuntu ~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b9056

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907028991 3907026944  1,8T 83 Linux
```

The drive is available as sdc1

```
xxx@ubuntu ~ $ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 8a359ebe:d9785fdb:e368bf24:bd0fce41 (local to host ubuntu)
  Creation Time : Sat Oct  8 13:55:02 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 1953513408 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 1953513408 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Dec 29 17:17:56 2018
          State : clean
Internal Bitmap : present
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : d5e354f3 - correct
         Events : 23978


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       49        2      spare         /dev/sdd1

   0     0       0        0        0      removed
   1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2     2       8       49        2      spare         /dev/sdd1
```

Quick check on mdadm

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
**mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc**
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md0
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 2 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 0 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
```

In the next step I've tried to mount the remaining disk as outlined in other posts.

```
lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      2,7T                   disk
└─sda1   2,7T btrfs             part /x-O
sdb    931,5G                   disk
└─sdb1 931,5G ext3              part /x-b
sdc      1,8T                   disk
└─sdc1   1,8T linux_raid_member part
sdd      2,7T                   disk
└─sdd1   2,7T btrfs             part /x-raid_A
sde      2,7T                   disk
└─sde1   2,7T btrfs             part
sdf    465,8G                   disk
├─sdf1 463,9G ext4              part /
├─sdf2     1K                   part
└─sdf5   1,9G swap              part [SWAP]
sdg      2,7T btrfs             disk /x-raid_B
sdh      2,7T btrfs             disk
```

The mount itself failed with an error message

```
xxx@ubuntu ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 disk1
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

Q1: In case I'm on the right track. How to overcome the problem ?

Based on the limited success I've decided to reassemble a raid 1 device
only with a single disk using force.

```
xxx@ubuntu ~ $ sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
```

This doesn't helped me to get further.

```
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
```

From here I start to feel lost. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
SFx

Comment: What if you assembe in readonly mode: `sudo mdadm —assemble —readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1`...

Comment: You might also first try to set the second drive to failed. `mdadm —examine` appearently still lists it as a spare. Do: `sudo mdadm —manage /dev/md0 —fail /dev/sdd1`, then try to assemble. You can also use `—remove` instead of `—fail`.

Comment: I've removed the spare device - Next step is to re-assemble the raid. Thanks a lot for the hint ...

Comment: Unfortunately, assemble command failed. So far, I have an empty md0 raid listed as inactive.
/dev/md0:
  Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 0
  Preferred Minor : 0
  Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Update Time : Sun Dec 30 02:34:54 2018
          State : active, FAILED, Not Started
 Active Devices : 0
 Failed Devices : 0
 Spare Devices : 0
 Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2       0        0        2      removed

Comment: /dev/md0:  
  Version : 0.90  
  Creation Time : Sat Oct  8 13:55:02 2016  
  Raid Level : raid1  
   Raid Devices : 2  
   Total Devices : 0  
    Preferred Minor : 0  
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent  
    
    Update Time : Sun Dec 30 02:34:54 2018  
    State : active, FAILED, Not Started  
    Active Devices : 0  
 Failed Devices : 0  
  Spare Devices : 0  
  
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State  
       0       0        0        0      removed  
       2       0        0        2      removed  
    
`

Comment: `sudo mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1`
mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md0
mdadm: giving up.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed to stop mdadm in advance. Seems like I'm getting closer. `mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1` provides a **clean, degraded** raid system.

Comment: I added this as an answer. You could accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, mdadm considers your RAID 1 array "clean", which is not the case. You should explicitly tell mdadm that your second (sdd1) disk has failed, remove it and mount the RAID 1 array in read only mode (to ensure that you can safely make a copy/backup or rebuild your RAID 1 array).

So, if you do the following:

```
sudo mdadm -—manage /dev/md0 —-fail /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm -—manage /dev/md0 —-remove /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm —-assemble —-readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
```

this should give you a clean, degraded RAID 1 array.

If you want to replace the disk, follow the reverse order: add the disk, rebuild the array en mount md0, like this:

```
sudo mdadm —-manage /dev/md0 —-add /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm --assemble --run --update=resync /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```